# From vectors to arrays c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, signal-processing

I have 6 functions taken from a toolbox for signal processing where a lot of vectors are used. Due to some memory issues on my DSP I need to use arrays instead. Is there an easy way to convert vectors to arrays and also the functions used i.e. insert, push_back, erase etc.?

Comment: vectors are essentially arrays, and you're losing nothing with using them. Raw arrays are error prone. Also, I doubt your memory issues come from using vector.  Have you looked where it came from?

Comment: Unless you write your own array class, you won't have the functions `push_back` etc on raw arrays.

Comment: Regarding the memory issue, I have tried to make a vector (locally) with the size 1024, but do to other local variables being present it doesn't fit on the stack. The stack is limited too 4k. What is really the size difference between decalaring a vector and an array? It has too be some difference since I can easily make an array of that size? And I have to add that I'm programming on a DSP with limited memory?

Comment: C++11 has the `std::array` class with a similar interface to `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the guarantee that c++ vector element storage is contiguous in memory and use

```
Type *array = &vector[0];
```

to get a "pointer to an array" out of a vector.

Comment: Or use the `data()` member function.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @GreyGeek. I formatted the answer to look acceptible. You may want to learn about formatting on SO yourself soonish :) http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @chris: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data data() is new with C++11 so he may not have access to it just yet.

Comment: @Borgleader, Of course, just putting it out there that it's meant for the purpose of getting access to the underlying data.

Comment: Yeah, it was a good suggestion I just thought it was worth mentioning because I've made the suggestion in the past and some people couldn't follow it because their compiler didn't support it.

Comment: The problem is that I can't even declare a vector. It takes up to much memory for some reason. But doing this with an array works fine. I find this very odd!?

Comment: @shizzle, can't declare a vector , take too much space ? maybe you need to use the constructor with a fixed number of element , something like std::vector<int>(4);

Comment: I have tried that. I'm good to go if the vector is smaller than 1000. But I need larger vectors so that becomes a problem.